# Which one of the components define the charging speed of a battery?

Tags: batteries, current

Battery chargers are often defined by its power in watts.

I will give two examples of two chargers of same wattage:

- The first one charges with a voltage of 1 V and a current of 5 A (so 5 W).
- The second one charges with a voltage of 5 V and a current of 1 A (so 5 W).

Which one will charge the battery faster? If the battery supports all those volatage/current combinations.

Is it the first one with 1 V and 5 A because the current defines the charging speed, or is it the same charging speed of the two, because the voltage and the current are both responsible for the charging speed?

Comment: "*But I will give 2 examples of 2 chargers ...*" Where did you come across a 1 V charger? Chargers usually give out a voltage a little higher than the battery chemistry voltage otherwise they can't push current into the battery / cell. I don't know any battery that can be charged at 1 V. So, to answer your question the 5 V charger will charge a 3.7 V cell faster than the 1 V charger which will never charge the cell.

Comment: The question is very broad, because the charging process itself must be explained before the question can be answered at all

Comment: The question does not make sense because a battery *cannot* support "all combinations of those voltages/currents". It's not a fair comparison.

Answer (score 2):

These are for two very different battery packs. I’m guessing these are theoretical battery chargers.

Your first one is apparently a 1V 5A charger. Assuming that these are charging values, not input values, then this is for a battery with the maximum voltage of just under 1V, and which can cope with 5A charging current. This would charge a 0.9V, 5Ah battery in (just over) 1 hour. Or a 0.9V, 10Ah battery in (just over) 2 hours.

Your first one is apparently a 5V 1A charger. Assuming that these are charging values, not input values, then this is for a battery with the maximum voltage of just under 5V, and which can cope with 1A charging current. This would charge a 4.75V, 5Ah battery in (just over) 5 hours. Or a 4.75V, 10Ah battery in (just over) 20 hours.

If we put the 1V, 5A charger on the 4.75V battery, at best nothing would happen. The battery would stay in whatever charge state it was in. Worse case, it would do some undefined damage to the charger and the battery, while discharging the battery in some unknown method.

If we put the 5V 1A charger on the 0.9V battery, it could (as long as there are good design features) charge the battery at 1A. I would never do this as there are a lot of ways where this could end with explosions, fire and death.

Both chargers charge at 5W, so 5Wh per hour. The difference is the voltage they are charging at. The voltage a battery operates at is fundamental to the battery technology and set up.

A good battery charger operates in CC-CV method; Constant Current, Constant Voltage. This works but pushing a constant current into the battery until its around 80-90% charged, and then the system changes to constant voltage, where it puts a slightly higher voltage across the cell (4.5V across a 4.2V li-ion cell for example) and holds in there trickling in that last bit of charge.

Now the limiting factor in battery charging, which is what you’ve asked at the start of the question comes down to:

- Battery technology, some chemistries limit the way the batteries can be charged
- Battery pack design, charging the batteries causes heat, this heat is bad. So you need to design you pack to remove the heat
- Charge controller, when charging at a constant current you need to control this. How the controller is designed will set this
- Power supply, the power to charge the battery needs to come from somewhere. This is an often over looked thing for EVs, yes a 100kW charger will charge the car faster, but the mains grid can only let you have 20kW as 4 other people are trying to charge in the area.

So from your question: they both charge the battery they are designed for. They both put the same amount of power across. But voltages are not interchangeable.

Answer (score 1):

Your question:

> Which one (Charger) will charge the battery faster? If the battery supports all those volatage/current combinations.

Some preliminary information here:
Battery is an electrochemical device that stores electrical energy promoting chemical reactions that can be recovered as supplying current when the battery discharges.
These chemical reactions happen by the total amount of “Coulombs” or Amperes x time.
That is why it is so common to express battery capacity in mAh (for AA batteries) or AH (for car batteries) - even more when the voltage is known:

- NiCd and NiMH battery: V = 1.2V.
- Lead Acid “12V”: V = 13V aprox.
- Lithium as 18650: V = 3.7~4.2V.
- When voltage of a battery pack is unknown, then the Product of voltage x Ah is expressed in WattH or simply Wh.

So, let’s remind that **each battery to be charged needs a higher voltage than the voltage it delivers**.

In this case, that **First 1V x 5A charger** can only be used to **partially charge** one NiMH cell. It will charge up to 5A, if battery accepts such current. It may be damaged because most AA batteries are rated as 2000mAh (in reality, not in fake ads) and 5000mA/2000 = 2.5C.
**Q**: So, how long it takes to fully charge a battery?
**A**: It never fully charges and may also damage the battery due to initial overcurrent - see ahead.

**Here comes another point: Maximum charging current**

Batteries usually don’t like to be Charger faster (= with more current) than 1C. So a 2000mAh should be charged at 2A, max! And using over-temperature and over-voltage protection circuits.
A safer value is 10%C = 2000mA, but even 50%C = 1000mA will work IF charging is terminated when voltage rises above 1.5V, or temperature reaches 50C, for instance.

**Q**: What about that **second charger**?
**A**: It can charge One Lithium battery (4.2V Full), or up to 3 NiMH cells.  BUT it is assumed it contains overcurrent, overvoltage, and overtemperature protections - they should be included, or battery may leak (NiMH) or even catch fire/explode (Lithium).

**Final Answer to your Question:**

**Real-life Answer**: The Charger that will “*charge faster*” is in fact **the only one** that also will be able to fully charge something practical. **It is the Second (5V x 1A) one.**

**For just an hypothetical** scenario: If you abstract reality and consider any electrochemical efficiency as 100%, neglect current limitations (due to battery size and internal wiring, electrodes area, etc), **then if**:

- Assuming both batteries have the **same Ah** capacity, **then** the charger with **Higher current is faster**.
- Assuming both batteries have the **same Wh** capacity, **then** *both chargers are* **equally fast**.